# Term for types of first person plural

Tags: grammar, terminology, personal-pronouns

I've noticed that there are two types of first person plural – one where the addressee is included, and one where she or he isn't.  For example:

With addressee included:

- Let us go.
- What's our plan?
- Where are we going?

With addressee not included:

- We want you to come along.
- Are you with us?

One can see that whether first person plurals *we* or *us* includes the addressee largely depends on context.
My question is this:

> Is there a term for these two types of **first person plurals**? Are there any words in English that distinguish these two types?

If this is more appropriate for Linguistics.SE (I'm not sure) here's an additional question: Does *any* language distinguish between these two types of first person plurals?

Comment: Related: [Context to distinguish “we” inclusive versus exclusive (closed)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42149/context-to-distinguish-we-inclusive-versus-exclusive) Re: other languages, check out [Maori](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/312/300).

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/599044/2085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cinderella: *"Hooray! We're going to the ball!"*
>
> Ugly Sister: *"No, **we're** going to the ball. **You're** staying home to do the housework."*

There's no single generic way to contextualise inclusive/exclusive *we/us/our* - in the above example, the spoken emphasis makes it clear that although Cinderella uses *"we"* inclusively, the Ugly Sister is *definitely* using it exclusively.

In other cases you might need to rely on background knowledge of what makes sense *(Cameron says "We want to reduce tax rates")*, or it might be implicit through other aspects of phrasing *("We will fight you all the way")*.

Addressing OP's specific question, the (somewhat more extensive) technical term is [clusivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clusivity), but we also often refer to the *inclusive* (or *exclusive*) *we*.

I'll also just note that in many spoken dialects, *inclusive you* can include the speaker - *"I like this place! They give you whatever you want!"*.

Comment: Why the down vote? There's a perfect example, even.

Comment: @Kris: I think I have a secret [antonym of admirer] here on ELU. I'll upvote yours though, because I think it's worth noting that the ambiguity isn't unique to English (something which I could have thought of for myself, since I know just about enough French to know it exists there). Personally I think we often *like* to have that ambiguity, because it can leave a little "wiggle room" in delicate social interactions.

Comment: That there's been fly-by down voters around is no secret and neither are they after you alone.

Comment: @Kris: Hmm. I've only really noticed it in the last couple of weeks. It's not normally enough to topple a good answer unless there aren't many upvotes anyway - which, as in this case, is because it's not apparently a fascinating question.

Comment: You may want to emphasize te fact that its called incl/excl OUR or clusivity. That was my main question; the answer is sort of hidden in yours :/

Comment: @Manishearth: Per the quotated usage [here in 2005](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=P8Gr3VOK7KoC&pg=PA238&dq=clusivity&hl=en&sa=X&ei=h4mLT92zK4Wx8QOtk_jUCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=clusivity&f=false), I think we're not dealing with particularly long-established terminology here. You're welcome to "know" what it's called for yourself, but I've no special reason to favour any particular words - they're all reasonably transparent neologisms, one as good as another.

Comment: ...[this from 2010](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9zcxQqmkgE0C&pg=PA118&dq=%22clusivity%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=94qLT5T6A8e_0QW5s7HeCQ&ved=0CF4Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22clusivity%22&f=false) says *clusivity* is "newly-coined", and implies that was primarily from a 2005 publication.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing new to this.  It's always been known, as the exclusive vs. inclusive FPP.

It's not unique to English.

And, yes, separate words exist in many languages.