# What is the numb sensation in the mouth caused by some fruits called?

Tags: single-word-requests, plant-physiology

There are some fruits<sup>*</sup> that cause a peculiar (unpleasant) numb sensation in the mouth. An unripe [persimmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persimmon) or a [quince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quince) are two examples that come to mind. I can't describe the feeling any more eloquently so my bet/hope is that you will know what feeling I am talking about.

Is there a word in English that describes the mentioned quality of these fruits and/or the sensation in the mouth?

<sub>*I don't know that only fruit can cause it, but I can't think of anything else at the moment.</sub>

Comment: Szechuan pepper has a similar effect (though it's more like your tongue goes all tingly and buzzy for a bit, and kind of goes numb), hence its Chinese name, 麻辣 _málà_, meaning literally ‘numbing chilli’. Not sure if that's the same kind of numbness—I've certainly never heard of a specific word for it.

Comment: I sometimes get it from Kiwi

Comment: Deadening is a word that comes to mind

Comment: I know the exact single word... in Russian. Yandex translates it as  the rather cumbersome "my mouth feels constricted/drawn", which doesn't actually sound like the same thing to boot. And needless to say, I've never heard anybody use either expression. The Russian word (*вяжет [во рту]*), on the other hand, is ubiquitous. Everyone knows and uses it. (Russians seem to have a dedicated word for everything happening in their mouths, another example being [*оскомина*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/1386/300), which is recognized as untranslatable into English.)

Comment: There's no natural term for it in English. You have described it, a numb or tingling sensation, but there's no special term. If there is a term surely it is a highly technical medical term.

Comment: I vividly remember, when I was about seven years old, being given an unripe American persimmon—a berry-size fruit—biting it, and feeling as though my tongue were suddenly covered with fur. My father (who had given it to me) explained that the persimmon had that effect because of "the alum in it."

Comment: Pineapple also does this and it kind of feels like you burned your tongue

Answer (score 25, accepted):

***Astringency*** or ***Puckering***

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste#Further_sensations)

> Some foods, such as unripe fruits, contain tannins or calcium oxalate
>   that cause an astringent or puckering sensation of the mucous membrane
>   of the mouth. Examples include tea, red wine, rhubarb, and unripe
>   persimmons and bananas.
>
> Less exact terms for the astringent sensation are "dry", "rough",
>   "harsh" (especially for wine), "tart" (normally referring to
>   sourness), "rubbery", "hard" or "styptic"

From [Education.com](http://www.education.com/science-fair/article/unpuckering-the-persimmon/)
(emphasis mine):

> Unripe persimmons are inedible because of the tannins that are
>   diffused throughout the fruit.  This tannins cause proteins in the
>   saliva and tongue to coagulate.  This coagulation of proteins produces
>   the **puckery, furry taste** in the mouth that we refer to as
>   ***astringency***.  This also happens with unripe bananas, some red wine and tea.

Comment: This seems to be the word(s) I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: *Astringency* & *puckering* are sure the effect. However, neither of them refers to the numbing of the sense of taste, which in fact may be a further effect of astringency/ puckering. Neither of the words relate directly to the senses in any way. https://www.google.com/#q=define+astringency & https://www.google.com/#q=define+pucker

Comment: @Kris But as I understood the question, the OP is asking for the numbing sensation in the mouth, the tannins in certain fruits etc. which cause the astringent taste one experiences. Now, it's been some time since I've tasted an unripe persimmon or a kiwi, so I can't remember if my tongue temporarily lost any feeling, but I do remember the general unpleasantness, and the coating which stuck to the tongue, and made my mouth feel quite dry. I presume it is this sensation, which the OP is asking for. If my answer is wrong, then modify your own to show why yours is the right one.

Comment: According to my experince, an easy and consistent way to aquire the experience described is to taste a raw [plantain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooking_plantain)

Answer (score 1):

*Desensitization* generic term

The effect of certain chemicals such as capsaicin (active component of chili peppers; capsicum) on possible suppression of the sense of taste has been studied and it has been found that oral capsaicin reduces certain but not all taste sensations. There doesn't seem to be a specific name to such desensitization of the taste buds.

Certain foods (e.g. fats/ proteins) may leave a waxy residue on the tongue, also causing a suppression of the taste buds.

Answer (score 1):

It's called ***hypogeusia*** - a diminished acuteness of the sense of taste. Related to this is ***dysgeusia*** - impaired or abnormal taste sensation. Although these conditions are caused by disease processes, temporary disturbances in taste can be caused by certain naturally occurring ingredients (by interfering with the normal functioning of taste receptors).

A less commonly used term is ***parageusia*** - the most familiar example of which is metallic taste from certain medications. ***Cacogeusia*** on the other hand is a *hallucination* or *illusion* of unpleasant taste, as seen in epilepsy.

Correction: *Cacogeusia* is now applied more generically to include real perception of bad taste. Example: the transient cacogeusia resulting from some varieties of pine nuts: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0266435612000101

The suggested term *astringency* is misleading. It is a generic term like *numbness*, not specific to taste in the mouth, strictly speaking not a sensation and certainly has no connotations of a numb sensation. You have *astringent skin lotions* for example.

Comment: Is there a tingling feeling associated with this? Is it caused by eating some kinds of fruit?

Comment: Yes - that would strictly come under the term dysgeusia.

Comment: I think the OP is not asking about -taste- (sweet, salt, etc) but about the tactile sensation. Tingling and numbness are not tastes.

Comment: There is no such thing as numbness and tingling that is distinct from the sole function of taste buds - taste. All impairments in perception including absence of taste (numbness) or what is described here as 'tingling' are simply that - impairment of taste. As Kris explains below it is somewhat related to desensitization of receptors.

Comment: If you touch your tongue with your finger, do you taste your finger or feel it? After you lick a stamp, do you feel the flavor or do you taste it? The tactile sense and the chemical (flavor) senses are distinct.

Comment: That's a completely different story! The present context is clearly that of taste related to foods- and hence restricted to taste buds - it has nothing whatsoever to do with touching with finger!

Answer (score 1):

I've always called it "[setting one's teeth on edge](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/312600.html)".

> Literally, to cause an unpleasant tingling of the teeth. More generally, the expression is used to describe any feeling of unpleasant distaste.

[The Phrase Finder]

Comment: Hi, Kate. I've just edited your answer as a link-only answer is not encouraged on ELU because the link can change in the future (and it could be flagged as low-quality by the system). Please take a look and try to follow this format next time.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure that this is exactly what you are describing, but it sounds like **[paresthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paresthesia)**

> a sensation of tingling, tickling, prickling, pricking, or burning of a person's skin with no apparent long-term physical effect. The manifestation of a paresthesia may be transient or chronic.

Some of these sensations are commonly called *pins and needles*.

There is also an allergic reaction in the mouth called [oral allergy syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_allergy_syndrome) (OAS) characterized by

> an itching or burning sensation in the lips, mouth, ear canal, and/or pharynx.

Comment: Is the same feeling that results from our limbs "falling asleep"?

Comment: @MrHen Yes, that is one version of paresthesia.