# What's the English for "allappare"?

Tags: translation, expression-choice

This  is essentially a translation question and as such off-topic, but please bear with me  for a moment.

***[Allappare](https://it.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/allappare)***  is an Italian verb that is used to refer to the ***astringent effect that you may experience when you eat unripe fruits***, ( persimmons and bananas for instance) ***with the result that your mouth and  tongue  become dry and your ability to chew is temporarily limited.***

The [English equivalent expression](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano-Inglese/A/allappare.php)  , according to most reliable dictionaries, apprears to be ***[set someone's teeth on edge](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/set+teeth+on+edge)***, which, by any definition I could  find online, doesn't actually correspond to the meaning cited above and is used mainly in a ***[figurative](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/set+teeth+on+edge) sense:***

> - If something, ​especially a ​noise, sets ​your ​teeth on ​edge, it ​annoys you very much:
>     *That DJ's ​voice really sets my ​teeth on ​edge.*

Questions:

- What the English expression that best fit  the definition of "allappare" cited above?
- What is the literal meaning of  "set someone's teeth on edge"? How close is it to the description given above of "allappare"?

Comment: *dry mouth*? bitterness?

Comment: @DanBron -       That is the common effect, the term refers specifically to eating something sour, unripe, (generally fruit)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure there exists such a term, though it would be a useful word to have. It could describe [told old Sylvester & Tweety cartoon](http://deeperintomovies.net/journal/image11/janshorts08.jpg) perfectly [aptly](http://abovethelaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Alum-Sylvester-Tweety-290x290.jpg). I did check [an old column in The Straight Dope about this experience](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1397/what-is-alum-and-will-it-make-someones-mouth-shrink-like-in-the-cartoons), but it didn't offer and useful terminology.

Comment: @DanBron - How on target is "set someone's teeth on edge" ? Not much IMO.

Comment: I tend to use that more for noxious sounds (nails grating on a backboard, a singer hitting a sour note, etc).

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132194/what-is-the-numb-sensation-in-the-mouth-caused-by-some-fruits-called/132218#132218

Comment: There is a link between the two expressions: the King James Bible translation of Jeremiah 31:29 runs "In those days they shall say no more, The fathers have eaten a sour grape, and the children's teeth are set on edge." The metaphor is probably a reference to the Mosaic law (Deuteronomy 24:16) that "Parents are not to be put to death for their children, nor children put to death for their parents; each will die for their own sin."

Comment: English for “allappare” is [*astringency*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astringent) which has no verb form.

Comment: @Mazura - astringency is "astringenza". I guess there is an expression used to verbalize astringency.

Answer (score 16):

The sensation is said to *cause the mouth to pucker*.  From [*Up North Again: More of Ontario's Wilderness, from Ladybugs to the Pleiades*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hLYfAQAAIAAJ&q=%22mouth%20to%20pucker%22&dq=%22mouth%20to%20pucker%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2zqqG_rvMAhWHyj4KHbTmBwkQ6AEILzAE) by D Bennet and T Tiner:

> Chokecherries are not as dangerous as their name suggests, though they
>   can taste harsh and astringent, causing the **mouth to pucker** and
>   dry.

Comment: This appears to be a close fit, any suggestion on the "teeth on edge"" part of the question?

Comment: @Josh61 - Trying to [swallow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swallowing) something bitter has a pharmacological effect on the body when sensed by the lingual nerve (?) of the tongue. "Any food that is too dry to form a bolus will not be swallowed." I surmise that a similar function is at play for astringents, one that seals the esophagus; involuntarily jutting the lower jaw forward: *setting your teeth on edge*.

Comment: @Mazura - it is clear that "teeth on edge" is part of the "consequences" of eating unripe fruits, but it does  not suggest the exact meaning. It strikes me that reliable  dictionaries suggest it as the closest translation considering that it is mainly used  in a figurative sense. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Josh61 - That's my theory as to why that idiom was chosen (the 'bitter-gag-reflex' is proving hard to research). BTW, that's how I like my bananas. I think that when *allappare* is used *for a sound*, it is figurative (you'd have to tell me). Otherwise, with food, it's referring to the "gag reflex" (for lack of a better term). *Nails down a chalkboard* stimulates mine, as does the sound of tearing cloth... "Man, that DJ's ​voice is really *astringent*."

Answer (score 1):

*Set one's teeth on edge* –[phrases.org.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/312600.html)

> Literally, to cause an unpleasant tingling of the teeth. More generally, the expression is used to describe any feeling of unpleasant distaste.
>
> The earlier form of the phrase was 'to edge the teeth' and described the feeling of sensitivity caused by acidic tastes, like raw rhubarb.

My teeth have never tingled; I've no idea what they're talking about.

> [Astringency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astringent) is also the **Dry, Puckering Mouthfeel** caused by tannins found in many fruits such as blackthorn (sloe berries), Aronia chokeberry, chokecherry, bird cherry, quince and persimmon fruits, and banana skins. The tannins (which are types of polyphenols) **bind the salivary proteins, causing them to precipitate or aggregate and lead to a rough "sandpapery" or dry sensation in the mouth**. Tannins are found in some red wines and teas. A small amount of astringency is expected in some wines, especially young red wines made from grapes such as cabernet sauvignon and merlot. –Wiki

Astringents do not directly inhibit your ability to masticate. They cause a reduction in the effectiveness of your saliva making it difficult to swallow.

---

*As a part of the *gag reflex*, a mechanism that I do not fully understand, with your tongue in contact with polyphenols (i.e., tannins) you will find your teeth have a temporarily malocclusion; a by-product of the esophagus involuntarily closing; where your teeth will literally *be on edge*. [*citation needed]

The idiom captures *"Bleh!"* quite well. Say it, and see how far your lower jaw juts forward... and then try to close your mouth.

> YUCKY FOODS THAT **[MAKE] ME GO BLEH!** on [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/jackalacka0309/yucky-foods-that-me-go-bleh/)

Originally, I agreed that the idiom wasn't, "on target." Now I think it's somewhat cheeky (apt, but not required, to be simultaneously figurative and literal) and *close enough for government work*.